# Library for exposing metadata about golang struct

Tags: go

In https://github.com/andig/evcc I'm using mapstructure and validator to handle yaml-based configuration. Moving to web-based configuration I'd like to implement the config ui driven by the configuration options implemented in the backend.

To do so I need to expose meta data about the config structs like:

- field types (string, bool)
- structural information (mapstructure squash tags)
- required, excluded (validator tags)

The expected result is a tree of fields with additional meta information.

The key to do so is reflection of course. I'd like to know if there is any go library already doing so?

Comment: (Wanted to comment but my reputation is not high enough) I would be interested to work on if there's no existing library for it.
I'm not fully following the requirement though. Can you give an example?